# borrar múltiples registros con un metodo

Tags: java

Buenas necesito que este método me borre varios registros que se guardan llamados dirección pero solamente me borra de a un registro por ves que puedo hacer?

```js
public void eliminarDireccion(DireccionVendedorDTO direccion) {
  LOGGER.info("eliminarDireccion" + direccion);
  List < DireccionVendedorDTO > tmp = new ArrayList < DireccionVendedorDTO > ();
  List < DireccionVendedorDTO > dirs = this.getDirecciones();

  for (DireccionVendedorDTO dir: dirs) {
    if (!dir.getIdDireccion().contentEquals("" + direccion.getIdDireccion())) {
      tmp.add(dir);
    }
  }
  eliminarDireccion.add(direccion);


  this.setDirecciones(tmp);
  this.setDireccionesEliminar(eliminarDireccion);
  this.agregarDireccion();
  this.setMostrarBotones(true);

}
```

Comment: Hola @anderson andres, para poder ayudarte es necesario que nos expliques un poco todo lo que no vemos del código, pero para empezar, hay algo que es erróneo, tu método se llama **eliminarDireccion** y después haces referencia a un objeto del mismo nombre **eliminarDireccion.add(direccion);**,

Comment: @MarcePuente hola si que pena es que asi me lo entregaron pero no entiendo y en este momento un ejemplo registro tres direcciones borro dos vuelvo a cargar y en vez de mostrarme una me muestra dos osea solo me borra uno lo que esta en <> son listas que se usan para poder llamar los campos que se llenan